# $http POST fails in AngularJS, succeeds in google REST client

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http-post

I have the following code:

```
updatelist = 
[
{
parser: {
delimiter: "",
parser_name: "History Record",
id: 3675,
isEnabled: "Y",
isFixedWidth: "N",
parsertype: "Table",
postprocessing: ""
},
parserdetail: [
{
ColumnName: "",
ColumnWidth: 0,
Delimiter: "", 
EOL: "Y", 
KeySignature:"Boot History Record", 
KeySignaturePosition: "Left",
OrderNum: 1,
ParserSection: "header",
TagName: "",
ValueType: ""
},

{
ColumnName: "S.No.",
ColumnWidth: 4,
Delimiter: "", 
EOL: "Y", 
KeySignature:"", 
KeySignaturePosition: "",
OrderNum: 1,
ParserSection: "body",
TagName: "SNumber",
ValueType: "nums"
}
]
}
]

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "https://myurl/parserrulesupdate",
    data: $.param(updateList),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    responseType: 'json'
})
.then(function(response) {
    returnData.resolve(response.data);  // returns list of ids
})
.catch(function(response) {
   console.error('POST error', response.status, response.data);
   returnData.reject();
})
```

The above http call fails with response 500

However, if I do the same POST with the same data through Google REST client, it succeeds. I am scratching my head at this point. If you could shed some light on why it is happening, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: 500 means server error. Could you debug, and check parameters that you get in server-side for both cases?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your server side code, in particular the input object, but i think problem could be here:

```
data: $.param(updateList)
```

Try to pass object directly like this:

```
data: updateList
```